# Dataflow wordcount example says I need to specify a --gcpTempLocation parameter

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I ran the example [wordcount java quickstart with maven command](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven)

```
mvn -Pdataflow-runner compile exec:java \
  -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
  -Dexec.args="--project=<PROJECT_ID> \
  --stagingLocation=gs://<STORAGE_BUCKET>/staging/ \
  --output=gs://<STORAGE_BUCKET>/output \
  --runner=DataflowRunner \
  --region=<REGION>"
```

but I got this stack trace

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< org.example:word-count-beam >---------------------
[INFO] Building word-count-beam 0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ word-count-beam ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ajamato/beam_starter/word-count-beam/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ word-count-beam ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ word-count-beam ---
Apr 01, 2021 10:35:07 AM com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials runningOnComputeEngine
INFO: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
[WARNING] 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:227)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:154)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.runWordCount (WordCount.java:176)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.main (WordCount.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:154)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.runWordCount (WordCount.java:176)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.main (WordCount.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataflowRunner requires gcpTempLocation, but failed to retrieve a value from PipelineOptions
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions (DataflowRunner.java:282)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:154)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.runWordCount (WordCount.java:176)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.main (WordCount.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get application default credentials. Please see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for details on how to specify credentials. This version of the SDK is dependent on the gcloud core component version 2015.02.05 or newer to be able to get credentials from the currently authorized user via gcloud auth.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.auth.NullCredentialInitializer.throwNullCredentialException (NullCredentialInitializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.newCloudResourceManagerClient (GcpOptions.java:436)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create (GcpOptions.java:310)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create (GcpOptions.java:297)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:605)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:546)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke (ProxyInvocationHandler.java:171)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.getGcpTempLocation (Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions (DataflowRunner.java:280)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:154)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.runWordCount (WordCount.java:176)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.main (WordCount.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.758 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-01T10:35:07-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project word-count-beam: An exception occured while executing the Java class. Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions): InvocationTargetException: DataflowRunner requires gcpTempLocation, but failed to retrieve a value from PipelineOptions: Unable to get application default credentials. Please see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for details on how to specify credentials. This version of the SDK is dependent on the gcloud core component version 2015.02.05 or newer to be able to get credentials from the currently authorized user via gcloud auth. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is a bit confusing, because there are two parts. Simply [install gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) and run

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud config set project <my_project>
```

There is no need to specify the --gcpTempLocation parameter to resolve this error.